# MVC4 api routing can find one action but not another

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following MVC4 api controller:

```
public class VisitorController : ApiController
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    public Visitor Get(int id)
    {
        return db.Visitors.Find(id);
    }
    public void SaveNotes(int id, string notes)
    {
        var visitor = db.Visitors.Find(id);
        visitor.Notes = notes;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

the Get works but the SaveNotes doesn't. I can't figure out why, but at run time, SaveNotes can't be found. (For what it's worth, Application Insights can see the attempt to POST to it, and that it gets a 404 error. See: [image: link])

Here's how I'm trying to call it: I have a modal dialog, like so:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="notesModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Notes</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="notesForm">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="notesID"/>
                    <textarea id="notesTextarea" name="notes"></textarea>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="saveNotes();">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have two javascript functions;

```
    function showNotes(id) {
        $("#searchingModal").modal("show");
        $.ajax("@Url.Action("Get", "API/Visitor")/" + id)
            .done(function (data) {
                $("#searchingModal").modal("hide");
                $("#notesID").val(id);
                $("#notesTextarea").val(data.Notes);
                $("#notesModal").modal("show");
            })
            .fail(function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                $("#searchingModal").modal("hide");
                genericError(status, errorThrown);
            });
    }
    function saveNotes() {
        //alert("@Url.Action("SaveNotes", "API/Visitor")/");
        $.ajax({ url: "@Url.Action("SaveNotes", "API/Visitor")/", data: $("#notesForm").serialize(), method:"POST" })
            .done(function () {
                $("#notesModal").modal("hide");
            })
            .fail(function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                $("#notesModal").modal("hide");
                genericError(status, errorThrown);
            });
    }
```

The function showNotes works great. I run an ajax request, it calls Get on the visitor controller, a visitor is returned, I populate that textarea with the Notes field, and show the modal. The problem is saveNotes. Every time I click the save button on the modal I get the failure function instead of the done function. The errorThrown is "Not Found". So how is it that only one action can't be found? I've tried putting the `[HttpPost]` attribute on it. I've tried making the id a nullable int (even though it's already optional in the route config, see:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

). I've tried making savenotes return a string instead of void. I've tried using $.post instead of $.ajax.

Comment: Try setting your SaveNotes action to respond to POST. I believe it is setting itself to GET by default

Comment: @Ju66ernaut I have tried putting the [HttpPost] attribute on SaveNotes. Is there some other way to have it respond to post?

Comment: My mistake I saw you tried that after I posted the comment. Did you also add attribute routing to the WebApiConfig.cs?

Comment: Yep, that's where it is.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is to make a model to receive your complex type. Some class that has 'id' and 'notes' properties instead of 2 separate params

Comment: Baffling. That worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're getting post data, it *must* be an object. So make an object like

```
public class SaveNotesInput
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set;}
}
```

change your function to accept that class, like so:

```
public void SaveNotes(SaveNotesInput input)
```

and it should work.

(couldn't tell you why)

(Credit to Ju66ernaut's comment, I'm just making this an answer for easier searchability)